Weird output image on inference
I'm trying to inference image with upscaling model in flutter. but output image is not as expected.
Its seems problem in normalize or in output to image.
Orginal Image: https://i.sstatic.net/AJX5gj48.png
Output Image: https://i.sstatic.net/A2u3ahd8.png
Model Shape:
Model input shape: ['batch_size', 3, 'width', 'height']
Model output shape: ['batch_size', 3, 'width', 'height']

Logs:
flutter: Is normalized: true
flutter: Image normalized successfully.
flutter: Input tensor created successfully.
flutter: Width: 1428, Height: 804, Channel: 3

I tried this code and out of scope now.
  Future<void> inference() async {
    if (selectedImage == null) {
      debugPrint('No image selected');
      return;
    }

    if (selectedImage != null) {
      Float32List? floatData;
      try {
        img.Image normalizedImage =
            img.normalize(selectedImage!, min: 0, max: 255);
        Uint8List imageData = normalizedImage.getBytes(order: img.ChannelOrder.rgb);
        floatData = Float32List.fromList(
            imageData.map((byte) => byte / 255.0).toList());
        debugPrint("Is normalized: ${isNormalized(floatData)}");
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("Error during normalization: $e");
      }

      final shape = [1, 3, selectedImage!.width, selectedImage!.height];

      debugPrint('Image normalized successfully.');

      final inputOrt =
          OrtValueTensor.createTensorWithDataList(floatData!, shape);

      final inputs = {'input': inputOrt};

      debugPrint('Input tensor created successfully.');

      final runOptions = OrtRunOptions();
      final outputs = await ortSession.runAsync(runOptions, inputs);

      inputOrt.release();
      runOptions.release();

      outputs?.forEach((element) {
        final outputValue = element?.value;

        if (outputValue is List<List<List<List<double>>>>) {
          img.Image generatedImage = generateImageFromOutput(outputValue);
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Dialog(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: generatedImage.width.toDouble(),
                  height: generatedImage.height.toDouble(),
                  child: Image.memory(
                    Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(generatedImage)),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          debugPrint("Output is of unknown type");
        }
        element?.release();
      });
    }
  }

  img.Image generateImageFromOutput(
      List<List<List<List<double>>>> outputValue) {
    int width = outputValue[0][0].length;
    int height = outputValue[0][0][0].length;
    int channel = outputValue[0].length;

    print("Width: $width, Height: $height, Channel: $channel");

    // Create the image
    img.Image generatedImage = img.Image(width: width, height: height);

    // Set pixel values
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        // Extract RGB values from the output tensor data
        int r = (outputValue[0][0][x][y] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        int g = (outputValue[0][1][x][y] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        int b = (outputValue[0][2][x][y] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);

        // Set pixel value in the generated image
        generatedImage.setPixelRgb(x, y, r, g, b);
      }
    }
    return generatedImage;
  }


Why the Python tag?

Try updating the inner for loop.
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
          // Extract RGB values from the output tensor data
          double r = outputValue[0][0][0][y * width + x];
          double g = outputValue[0][0][1][y * width + x];
          double b = outputValue[0][0][2][y * width + x];
    
          // Scale and clamp the values
          int r_scaled = (r.clamp(0, 1) * 255).toInt();
          int g_scaled = (g.clamp(0, 1) * 255).toInt();
          int b_scaled = (b.clamp(0, 1) * 255).toInt();
    
          // Set pixel value in the generated image
          generatedImage.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(r_scaled, g_scaled, b_scaled));
        }
      }


Thanks for help, but i got
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..803: 804
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      _MyHomePageState.generateImageFromOutput (package:modelify/home_page.dart:148:40)
#2      _MyHomePageState.inference (package:modelify/home_page.dart:83:36)

